# Sequelize Dialect Error

Tags: node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js, lodash

I recently ran into a bizarre error with my app after installing lodash. I have no idea if it created any impact on my setup, but all of a sudden sequelize throws an error at the dialect property that `mysql` is not supported and cannot read `property 'dialectName' of undefined`. I'm not sure why this is happening because I have been using sequelize for a while and this never appeared.

Running with node `v0.10.40`

Full error:

```
/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:205
    throw new Error('The dialect ' + this.getDialect() + ' is not supported. S
          ^
Error: The dialect mysql is not supported. Supported dialects: mariadb, mssql, mysql, postgres, and sqlite. (TypeError: Cannot read property 'dialectName' of undefined)
    at new Sequelize (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/app-test/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:205:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/app-test/app/models/db-index.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/app-test/config/passport.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/app-test/app/controllers/site-routes.js:4:16)
```

Where my dialect is set:

db-index.js:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var path = require('path');
var config = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..','./config/config.js'));
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
    host:'localhost',
    port:'3306',
    dialect: 'mysql'
});

sequelize.authenticate().then(function(err) {
    if (!!err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err)
    } else {
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.')
    }
});

var db = {}

db.Member = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/member");

db.Organization = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/organization");

db.User = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/user");

db.DiscoverySource = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/discovery-source");

db.User.associate(db);
db.Organization.associate(db);
db.DiscoverySource.associate(db);

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

sequelize.sync();

module.exports = db;
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": "5.0.0"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.14.1",
    "cheerio": "^0.20.0",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.0",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "express-hbs": "^0.8.4",
    "jquery": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.10.6",
    "morgan": "^1.6.1",
    "mysql": "^2.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.8.1",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "sequelize": "^3.14.1",
    "session": "^0.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I put a possible solution in this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066755/22441730

Answer (score 3):

you must install pakage mysql:

```
npm install mysql --save
```

Good luck ^^

Comment: @RickJames Can you help?